# Copyright Symbol in footer not resizing with the rest of text (in Drupal 7)

Tags: html, css, drupal, view

Im trying to format the footer, and everything is working out fine except that the © won't resize with the rest of the text. I am using Drupal 7, and it is plain text inserted into the site with a views block.

The HTML:

```
<!-- !Tertiary Content Region -->
<div class="region region-tertiary-content">
    <div class="region-inner clearfix">
        <div id="block-views-footer-block" class="block block-views no-title" >
            <div class="block-inner clearfix">  
                <div class="block-content content">
                    <div class="view view-footer view-id-footer view-display-id-block view-dom-id-6f88dad9b3367d24dd76eca83bc3e291">
                        <div class="view-content">
                            <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
                                <div class="views-field views-field-body">        
                                    <div class="field-content">
                                        <p>© 2015 MySite</p>
               </div>  
               </div>  
               </div>
               </div>
               </div>
               </div>
               </div>
               </div>
               </div>
               </div>
<!-- !Footer -->
```

Excessive divs for one piece of content... maybe thats my problem but I didn't write this markup and have no intent of trying to change it now. I just need to get that copyright symbol to grow!

The CSS:

```
#block-views-footer-block {
background-color: #2e2d2c;
color: #ffffff;
position:relative;
top:-50px;
}
#block-views-footer-block p {
font-size: 25px;
position:relative;
top: 18px;
left: 20px;
}
```

Ive tried rewriting the different versions of hex, changing from formatted html to plain text, etc with no changes. I even copied and pasted in a (C) but it just doesn't seem to resize for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was that some of the stylesheet settings were not overriding in my @media only screen and(min-width:1025px) block, and the symbol is being positioned in a weird way. I still haven't figured out the positioning part, but the sizing part seems to work when I added !important.